# What is the size in Byte of this kind of float?

Tags: c#, memory, byte

I want to know what is the size in memory in bytes of this float number for example `-0,005606111`.

Comment: What programming language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation a [`float`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx) takes up 32 bits (4 bytes), a [`double`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9(v=vs.90).aspx) takes 64 bits (8 byteS) and a [`decimal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75(v=vs.90).aspx) takes 128 bytes (16 bytes).

Note, however that a `float` offers a precision of 7 digits, so it **won't**  be appropriate for storing the value `-0.005606111`. Instead, you should use a `double` (15-16 digits of precision) or a `decimal` (28-29 digits).

Comment: It takes 7 *significant* digits so float can store it just fine.  Keep in mind that the decimal point "floats".